# Mongoose Update document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using Node.js and mongoose Module, I am looking for a way to count how many documents a user has and then if they have more then 0 documents it would edit their existing document and add the input so at the end it would have the previous text + the text that the user sent, so far this is how much I gotten.

```
const List = require('../Models/list.js')
List.countDocuments({}, function(err, count) {
     if(count>0){
//edit document
} 
     else if(count=0){
const input = List.create({
          User: User.name,
          Songlist: args[0],
        })
    }

})
console.log('done')
```

here is how I think the code would look like

```
  List.update(User.name) => update Songlist into List.Songlist + '|' + args[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen an update method like that. I am a nodejs developer. well, maybe there's a way like that.

Here's how I do to update a document

await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(id, //here where I have written "id" you have to write the id of the document you want to update.
{ //here in this object you have to put the variables of updated values
title: title,
description:description,
product_id:product_id,
category,
price,
});

there is also another method

```js
await Product.findOneAndUpdate(name: 'asim', //let's suppose
{ //updated values
title:title,product: product
})
```

you can also read the documentation here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked, also for the example I showed doesn't follow any coding language, I just used it to show the process I wanted.